# Nodemailer not sending message

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I just set up my project and the contact form does not work. On localhost worked perfectly but when I'm testing it on server it doesn't send any message. I tried changing the port and directory but it doesn't work either. Thanks in advance

---

here is directory structure:

```
|-- /
|   |-- cgi-
|   |-- assets
|   |-- .env
|   |-- favicon
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- server.js
```

---

here is my code server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static('assets'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.name,
    to: process.env.DB_USER,
    subject: `Message from ${req.body.email}: ${req.body.subject}`,
    text: req.body.message,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send('error');
    } else {
      res.send('success');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: what hosting are you using?

Comment: strato - https://www.strato.de/

Comment: You should check if they support node deployment on there servers.